# How to know if Android device supports stereo recording?

Tags: android

The new Motorola RAZR supports stereo recording, but many other phones do not. How can I ask Android in a programmatic way if the device supports stereo recording?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entierly sure but have you checked this from the Developers site:

> public void setAudioChannels (int numChannels)
>
> Since: API Level 8 Sets the number of audio channels for recording.
>   Call this method before prepare(). Prepare() may perform additional
>   checks on the parameter to make sure whether the specified number of
>   audio channels are applicable. Parameters
>
> numChannels   the number of audio channels. Usually it is either 1
>   (mono) or 2 (stereo).

How about setting up for stereo and if it throws an exception - fall back on mono?

Comment: How does it work ? I need to record stereo on my upcoming project ?